# Insert in Binary Search Tree with duplicate Keys?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

Right now when I'm inserting Keys/Values into the BST and then searching them I get null values. I would like to get  some assistance on how to handle with duplicate keys.

```
    private Node put(Node root, final Key key, final Value value) {
    if (root == null)
        return new Node(key, value, 1);

    final int result = key.compareTo(root.key);

    if (result > 0)
        root.right = put(root.right, key, value);
    else if (result <= 0) {
        root.left = put(root.left, key, value);
    }
    root.size = size(root.left) + size(root.right) + 1;
    return root;
}

private Value get(final Node root, final Key key) {
    if (root == null)
        return null;

    final int result = key.compareTo(root.key);

    if (result > 0)
        return get(root.right, key);
    else if (result <= 0)
        return get(root.left, key);
    return root.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your get code needs an == check.  Your <= 0 check is grabbing the node to the left where you want < 0.  Your == check should return the root.value.

Something like:

```
private Value get(final Node root, final Key key) {
    if (root == null)
        return null;

    final int result = key.compareTo(root.key);

    if (result > 0)
        return get(root.right, key);
    else if (result < 0)
        return get(root.left, key);
    else if (result == 0)
        return root.value;
    else
        return null; //key not found
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I get only the first duplicate. Do I have to change something in my put method too?

Comment: Are you saying you want to insert duplicate keys with different values into a binary search tree?  This is not how binary search trees are supposed to work.  Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Verification

Comment: That's exactly what I want, but I have trouble achieving it.

Comment: This goes against binary search rules. A duplicate key should either be blocked or replace the old value.  Usually you would replace the old one.

Comment: If you wanted to have multiple values per key you could make each Node have a Value list List<Value> values = new ArrayList<Value>() instead of just one Value.  And when you insert you would add to that list.  This could achieve what you want but I still feel it is unadvisable.